# XCode Simulator changes to previous GPS location

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation

I have an geolocation type app that relies heavily on location services. Specifically, what it does is it changes to the old location for a split second, and then back to the current one.

I went to Edit Scheme, and have both checked and unchecked "Corelocation Allow Location Simulation" and have had the same issue. I change location by specifying a "custom location" on my simulator.

The problem seems to resolve itself if I use a different type of phone on the simulator. I have to eventually demo this app, and I know that it works well, but I don't want to be embarrassed because the XCode Simulator is acting up! I guess I can just keep restarting the simulator or using another type of phone, but I hope I can figure out another way to fix this.

This happens when I get the location with swiftlocation. I have other code in addition to what I have below, but that's basically the info (i.e. sourcelocation) that I'm sending to my DB.

```
    Location.getLocation(accuracy: .city, frequency: .continuous, success: { (_, location) in

    let sourceLocation = CLLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
```

Comment: Check the timestamp on `location`.  The location manager may be initially giving you an old cached location before it gets the updated one.

Comment: What value are you giving to locationManager.desiredAccuracy ? I am wondering whether reduced accuracy means it is falling back to the last 'good enough' value? For some of the values  you can see: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Getting_Location_Information_using_the_iOS_8_Core_Location_Framework_in_Swift - I couldn't find a table in the Apple docs for this.

Comment: Great ideas from both, thanks guys. I changed the accuracy from .city to .navigation, and I thought that was the answer, but then I still got a location blip with it reverting back to an old location. I'm going to try the timestamp...With that said, before my demo, I'm just going to make sure to reset the contents and settings of my simulator, just to be on the safe side. It definitely does work fine on devices.